# How to display database values on google map's marker dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, google-maps

**this is my code to fetch records from db and display users who are online**

```
$markers = array();         
$sql_locations1="SELECT DISTINCT uid,latitude,longitude from `location` where uid='$_REQUEST[locator_id]' ORDER by `date_time` DESC limit 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_locations1);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {                   
        $markers[] = array(
        'abc',
        $row['latitude'],
        $row['longitude'],          
        );      
        }?>
<div id="map_canvas" onload="initMap()"></div>
```

**as you can see 'abc' in array its static value that shows on each markers on map. what i want is user's name from db on markers of their own on the place of that 'abc' static value**
**i dont know how to get this db value on that place. below is my function for map**

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: "roadmap",
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629), // somewhere in the uk BEWARE center is required
        zoom: 1,
    };
    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode( $markers );?>;
     // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;
    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    //Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(5);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**please help me with the same thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a join query to fetch the user name from database and show it in map's info window :

```
// Allow each marker to have an info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
    })(marker, i));
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',  (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```